# Quality factor of RLC circuit

Tags: capacitor, passive-networks

I am trying to calculate the quality factor for the response curve of a series RLC circuit. I measured the voltage across the capacitor at several frequencies and calculated its ratio to the forcing voltage. The curve I obtained is as follows:
[image]

How is it possible to find quality factor when there no points where the curve reach -3db on the left side of the peak?

Comment: The Q factor of a series resonant circuit is simply XL / R (at resonance).

Comment: You have a VERY LOW Q.

Comment: You might try measuring voltage across the resistor rather than capacitor. I get component values of \$ C \approx 1.6nf \$ and \$ L \approx 0.011 H \$ for \$R=2193 \$

Answer (score 2):

\$Q=\dfrac{1}{2\zeta} = \sqrt{A_{pk}^2 + 1}\$  for peak gain Apk

When Q is the quality factor of resonance gain approaches 1 or less, we switch to damping factor as resonance becomes dampening factor is more relevant.

Rule of Thumb: **We approximate high Q to be just the resonant gain for Q>>1.**

> But in your case, Q is very low, and the peak/flat gain = 1.25
>
> If gain, Apk=1.25  then Q = 1.6 , or ζ = 1/3.2  **This is your answer from reading graph.**

Other useful formulae for 2nd order RLC filters depend if in series or parallel resonant mode.

\$X_C(\omega_o)=\dfrac{1}{\omega_oC}\$    and \$X_L(\omega_o)=\omega_oL\$

Consider a series LP filter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxKZIK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$\omega_o=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}=2\pi*f\$

Parallel resonant circuits for high Q,  Rp >> X(ωo) the impedance of both reactances: are low and equal so the current cycles between these and very little loss current in Rp. (underdamped)

- e.g. L=10uH, C=10uF Rp=100 , thus Q=100 at ωo=1e-5 f=√2*10kHz=14.14kHz

For series  resonant circuits: \$Q = \frac{1}{Rs} \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$
\$Q=\dfrac{\omega_o}{BW_{-3dB}}\$ for Bandpass filters (BPF)

[More math background on 2nd order systems](https://cnx.org/contents/Cy752CuW@4/Second-Order-Filters)

[image]

Normal for high Q we simplify this to just voltage or current peaking linear gain which you can convert to dB.

Another way is lookup on any "RLC Impedance Nomograph chart" and instantly find the unknown for any of the other knowns for L, C, Q, f, Z(f) using the log-log-log 3D chart like a slide rule. [For examples see here.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A17574%20RLC%20nomograph)

When Q=ζ=0.707, it is the common  Butterworth filter, which also has a  critically damped response with no overshoot or "unity" Voltage gain as shown above.

**For a more mathematical explanation [read here.](http://www.doe.carleton.ca/%7Ermason/Teaching/486-d.pdf)** from U of Carlton.

## Useful Q benchmarks and for fun

Q's of < 50 are easy in LC or active filters and >200 hard due to tolerances and thermal drift. However for Q > 10k it is easily possible with any piezo-crystal resonator. (MEMs, tuning fork and AT cuts) But with some Quartz SC-cut the Q => 100k only at one temperature regulated by an oven, (OCXO). Cesium clocks it is even higher, the phase noise is poor so they lock SCt OCXO to the Cesium clock.

This Q factor thus is related to noise BW, jitter, phase shift and the crystal has equivalent RLC paramters with L in the mH to Henries and C in the fempt-farads with ESR [Ohms] and a load capaitance [pF].

## 64k$ question

What is the Q of an atom?  ( hint it is the only lossless thing in nature)

Comment: How did you come up with this equation for Q?

Comment: I did it from memory, but this may help you https://cnx.org/contents/Cy752CuW@4/Second-Order-Filters

Comment: make sense yet?

Comment: Sim http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+5+50+5+50%0A%25+6+1183.069613694428%0AO+336+96+448+96+0%0Ag+336+224+336+256+0%0Ar+224+96+336+96+0+0.2%0Al+224+96+64+96+0+0.001+7.2856888691203805%0A170+64+96+32+96+3+20+1000+5+0.1%0Ac+336+96+336+224+0+0.001+0%0Ao+4+16+0+34+5+0.00009765625+0+-1%0Ao+0+16+0+34+5+0.00009765625+1+-1%0A

Comment: Tony Stewart: I have some problems with the first line (Q=f(Apk). Example 1: Apk=1 (Butterworth) gives Q=1.414 (wrong); Example 2: Apk=1.414 (Chebyshev with 3dB ripple) gives Q=1.732 (wrong).

Comment: @LvW  Oops , what do you suggest?  ( Apparent vs X/R ?)

Comment: 4th order Butterworth uses Q1=0.54 , Q2=1.31, so Q= Q1*Q2 = 0.71

Comment: My only approach is to rewrite the following: Apk=AoQp/SQRT[1-(1/4Qp²)]. But it is not so easy...

Comment: Sounds better so as to use Pythagorean shift effects or ?  Yes this also affects GBW demand increase by 1+Qp²

Comment: What you wrote concerning Butterworth is very interesting. This surprising property applies to all Butterworth orders: The product of all Q-values always gives 0.7071. However, I never hav seen or found a theoretical derivation for this rule.

Comment: Tue.. 10th Order B. filter Q= 0.51, 0.56, 0.71, 1.1, 3.2  ... Product of all real gains = 0.71  rather than inverse of damping factor products/2^(n/2)

Comment: Any suggestions to improve answer are welcome especially where Q is or not Apk using Pythagorean apparent gain

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the DEFINITION of the Q-value.

- For second-order LOWPASS functions (as in the described example) there is only one single definition: The Q-value is the POLE QUALITY FACTOR Q=Qp, which is defined based on the pole location sp in the s-plane.

Hence, the 3dB points of the magnitude plot are not relevant for for the Q-value of a lowpass.

- The same applies to second-order BANDPASS functions - however, this pole quality Qp is idenbtical to the Q value defined as Q=fo/BW (mid frequency devided by 3dB-bandwidth).

**Example**: Obviously, the problem description shows a second-order lowpass and the Q-value is the pole-Q which can be found using the expression: 2Qp²=wp²/(wp²-wm²) with pole frequency wp and frequency wm at peak magnitude.